# Adapting hyperledger caliper with custom hyperledger fabric network "fabcar"

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-caliper

I was trying to test hyperledger fabric sample "fabcar" network with hyperledger caliper. I have edited caliper's "simple" benchmarks config.yaml and fabricConifg.json according to the official documentation. I'm getting the following error when trying to run it:

> error: [instantiate-chaincode.js]: Failed to instantiate chaincodes: Error: Failed to send instantiate Proposal or receive valid response. Response null or status is not 200.
>
> error: [fabric.js]: Fabric chaincode install failed: Error: Failed to send instantiate Proposal or receive valid response. Response null or status is not 200.
>
> error: [bench-flow.js]: Error: Error: Failed to send instantiate Proposal or receive valid response. Response null or status is not 200.
>
> info: [demo.js]: [Transaction Info] - Submitted: 0 Succ: 0 Fail:0 Unfinished:0
>   info: [bench-flow.js]:

Here's my fabric config file-

```
{

  "fabric": {
    "cryptodir": "/home/kingbayeed/hyperledger/fabric-samples/basic-network/crypto-config",
    "network": {
      "orderer": {
        "url": "grpc://localhost:7050",
        "mspid": "OrdererMSP",
        "msp": "/home/kingbayeed/hyperledger/fabric-samples/basic-network/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/msp/",
        "server-hostname": "orderer.example.com",
        "tls_cacerts": "/home/kingbayeed/hyperledger/fabric-samples/basic-network/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/ca.crt"
      },
      "org1": {
        "name": "peerOrg1",
        "mspid": "Org1MSP",
        "msp": "/home/kingbayeed/hyperledger/fabric-samples/basic-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp/",
        "ca": {
          "url": "http://localhost:7054",
          "name": "ca-org1"
        },
        "peer1": {
          "requests": "grpc://localhost:7051",
          "events": "grpc://localhost:7053",
          "server-hostname": "peer0.org1.example.com",
          "tls_cacerts": "/home/kingbayeed/hyperledger/fabric-samples/basic-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt"
        }
      }

    },
    "channel": [
      {
        "name": "mychannel",
        "deployed": true,
        "config": "/home/kingbayeed/hyperledger/fabric-samples/basic-network/config/channel.tx",
        "organizations": ["org1"]
      }
    ],
    "chaincodes": [

      {"id": "fabcar", "path": "/home/kingbayeed/hyperledger/fabric-samples/chaincode/fabcar/go", "language":"golang", "version": "v1", "channel": "mychannel"}
    ],
    "endorsement-policy": {
      "identities": [
        {
          "role": {
            "name": "member",
            "mspId": "Org1MSP"
          }
        }


      ],
      "policy": {"1-of":[{"signed-by":0}]}
    },
    "context": {
      "invoke": "mychannel",
      "query": "mychannel"
    }
  },
  "info" : {
    "Version": "1.0.0",
    "Size": "1 Org with 1 Peer",
    "Orderer": "Solo",
    "Distribution": "Single Host"
  }
}
```

Comment: no answer anybody?